# PHP SSH2 ssh2_auth_password page while loading

Tags: php

I will using ssh2_auth_password for authentication to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and webpage while loading... not return any result.

### Test script:

```
if(($connection = ssh2_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 22)))
{
    $auth = ssh2_auth_password($connection, "guest", "guest");
    echo $auth;
    ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
    unset($connection);
    exit;
    if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, "guest", "guest"))
    {
        echo "Tunnel OK\n";
        ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
        unset($connection);
        exit;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
        ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
        unset($connection);
    }
} else {
    echo "timeout";
}
```

### Expected result:

Webpage not while loading... and return login success or fail

### Actual result:

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I wouldn't put the real IP of your SSH server in the question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat But only this server have this problem, and some server have this problem too, if have someone run test my script and him see everything is fine so my question is wrong :(

Comment: So then maybe it's a problem with the server and not the PHP code.  Is everything set up properly on the server?  Can you SSH to it normally?

Comment: @RocketHazmat My server running apache and php lastest version, i'm setup ssh2 & libssh2 lastest version too, i using Bitvise SSH Client on windows to login on this server and everything work fine but can't login ssh throw my php code with ssh2 lib. I will post this question to bugs  on php.net page but never get answer https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66941

Comment: That's not what `bugs.php.net` is for.  That's for bugs with PHP itself, not issues in code you're written.  There's a 99.99% chance that this isn't a PHP bug.

Comment: Also, you should probably change the passwords on your SSH servers.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Really i think ssh2 lib have problem, i will read php_ssh2 source c language and read libssh2 source too but can't find anything. I don't have any way for fix this to working fine and post my question in here is my last chance

Comment: So, you say "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."  Is this an error message you're seeing?   Where do you see this?  Is it a PHP error?  Is it a browser's page?  Do you have error reporting enabled in your PHP?  Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of this script.

Comment: Maybe it's a firewall issue on the server?  Have you checked that?  Have you looked at the SSH/auth logs on the SSH server?

Comment: I will enable all error reporting in php settings, read all log and can't find anything, when i run script, browser loading long time and finish with "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Comment: I running this script on localhost and disabled all firewall too but not working fine

Comment: That error is just shown by the browser, it's not useful to you.  You need to enable PHP error reporting and see what that says.

Comment: Okey i will try to fix it, anyway many thanks for you help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your English is fine :-)

Comment: Is `ssh2_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 22)` called successfully? Maybe the ssh2 extension isn't even installed?